# pm-suspend won't work with i3wm

Tags: command-line, suspend, configuration, i3-wm, pm-utils

I recently installed i3wm and I'm currently configurating it. But I'm looking for a way to suspend my computer, I found `pm-suspend`. The problem is that the command won't work. After executing `sudo pm-suspend`, my screen goes black and about 10s later, my screen goes back to my workspace.
Does anyone know how to resolve this issue ? Thanks

Comment: Does your computer suspend properly in for example Gnome Shell? Anyway, try  "systemctl suspend -i" (in principle you should not need root permissions).

Comment: When I'm not using i3 it work perfectly. And with 'systemctl suspend -i' it doesn't work too. I'm lost why i3 block every commands I've done  when I'm trying to suspend my computer.

Comment: Perhaps try with screen locking first, i.e. `i3lock && systemctl suspend -i`. i3lock "forks" so will immediately give way to the next command as the man pages indicate.

Comment: Well, I've restarted my PC and I've noticed that it accept to suspend one time. After it do the same thing black screen the goes to the i3lock... I think I'm gonna post an issue on i3wm's GitHub

Comment: Do you get prompted for a password when you type `sudo pm-suspend`?